# Результат из замыкания с возвращаемой анонимной функцией

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Я извиняюсь за такой вопрос, но спросить больше не у кого. Почему не работает код?

```js
function add(a) {
  return function() {
    return a + 1;
  }
}
var f = add(5);
console.log(f);

/*
объявляем функцию add и передаем ей параметр со значением 5, который станет в теле функции локальной переменной (var a = 5;).
В функции add имеется анонимная функция которая не имеет своего объекта переменных(лексического окружения), поэтому она по scope находит значение переменной "a" во внешнем объекте переменных, после чего выполняется и возвращается в функцию add виде выражения 5+1=6.

В переменную f мы записываем результат выполнения всей инструкции function add, равный 6. На деле не так, выводится код функции, подскажите, где я запутался?
*/
```

Comment: Когда Вы задаете вопрос "почему не работает", желательно описать ожидаемый результат.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо вызвать функцию, добавив после `f` круглые скобочки.

```js
function add(a) {
  return function() {
    return a + 1;
  }
}
var f = add(5);
console.log(f());
```

> я проверял код до написания вопроса в jslint, но он вместо подсказки о
>   необходимости добавления скобок, написал Expected ';' and instead saw
>   '}'.

Либеральные js парсеры позволяют не ставить ";", если потом идет, например, перенос строки. Но jslint на такие вещи реагирует.

Речь в этом предупреждении идет об отсутствии ";" после значения в `return`:

```
  return function() {
    return a + 1;
  }; // вот здесь
```

Отсутствие скобок после переменной `f` тоже синтаксической ошибкой не является - может быть Вы хотели вывести в консоль текст кода функции.

Comment: я проверял код до написания вопроса в jslint, но он вместо подсказки о необходимости добавления скобок, написал Expected ';' and instead saw '}'.  Что это означает? Ведь больше нет ошибок?